# notation: is not a factor of

Tags: notation

I know that a factor can denoted by |, for e.g:

if $x$ is divisible by $y$, then it can be notated by $x|y$.

However, I do not know how to denote when $x$ is not a factor of $y$.

What is the notation for is "not a factor of"?

Comment: If I type \$\not|\$ here I get $\not|$. I wonder if that's acceptable notation for "not a factor of"?

Comment: Yeah, $\not|$ is fine.

Comment: Anyway, it should read as ‘is (not) a divisor’. The phrase ‘is a factor’ is used in the context of rings with unique factorisation, but ‘is a divisor of’ is a more general concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same symbol with a strike-through. I can think of a couple of ways.

$\texttt{\nmid}$
$$
\nmid
$$

$\texttt{\not|}$
$$
\not|
$$

Whatever suits you stylistically.

Comment: The latter is hard to quickly distinguish from $\vert$, IMO.

Comment: The former is *far* superior.

Comment: Agreed. $\texttt{\not}$ is maybe easier to remember and more versatile in a pinch! $\not \in$, $\not \exists$, $\not \subset$, etc...

Comment: \not \mid gives $\not \mid$, so \not has some smarts. To me, the obscure part is to know that \mid and | look the same, but have different semantics.